# Programmatically modify PS shortcut layout

Tags: powershell

I have successfully modified the common attributes of a a shortcut using Powershell; things like changing the icon, setting it to run elevated, etc.
But, in the case of a shortcut to PowerShell itself, that passes a script as an argument, there are some more attributes in the Layout tab of properties, and I would like to be able to modify those attributes as well.
But I can't seem to find any reference to how to get at them.
FWIW, I have been using PS to do this programmatically like [this](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/powershell-basics-console-configuration), but I find it problematic when used across different OSs and different versions of PowerShell. So, looking at alternatives.

Comment: The article you mention describes the only way that I know of to do what you are attempting, by using the `$Host.UI.RawUI` object.  Can you please expand on what sort of problems you are encountering across the different OS's and versions of PowerShell?

Comment: And, interestingly, I discovered a little more detail over the weekend. The issue seems to be that you can't start the script minimized and force a new size on it. If you start as a normal window it works fine. At least in Win10. Haven't tested both conditions in Win7 yet. Seems a little buggy that I can't push a new size on a minimized window, but at least I know now.